# How to add column which count distinct person any city

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the table like this:

```
Person    City    workingdate
A    Newyork    10.11.2015
A    Newyork    11.11.2015
A    Newyork    12.11.2015
B    Newyork    10.11.2015
B    Newyork    15.11.2015
B    Newyork    16.11.2015
B    Newyork    18.11.2015
```

I want to have a column which count distinct person within city:

```
Person    City    workingdate  countdistinctpersonincity
A    Newyork    10.11.2015             1
A    Newyork    11.11.2015             0
A    Newyork    12.11.2015             0
B    Newyork    10.11.2015             1
B    Newyork    15.11.2015             0
B    Newyork    16.11.2015             0
B    Newyork    18.11.2015             0
```

Can you please help me how to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(Person varchar(25),
City varchar(255),
workingdate varchar(10));

insert into Persons
values ('A', 'Newyork','10.11.2015'),
('A', 'Newyork','11.11.2015'),
('A', 'Newyork','12.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','10.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','15.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','16.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','18.11.2015');
```

Comment: what is your sql server version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, p2.*
FROM #Persons p
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT p1.Person) as countdistinctpersonincity
        FROM
            #Persons p1 
        WHERE
            p1.Person <> p.Person
            AND p1.City = p.City
            AND p1.workingdate = p.workingdate) p2;
```

Test code

```
CREATE TABLE #Persons
(Person varchar(25),
City varchar(255),
workingdate varchar(10))
insert into #Persons
values ('A', 'Newyork','10.11.2015'),
('A', 'Newyork','11.11.2015'),
('A', 'Newyork','12.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','10.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','15.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','16.11.2015'),
('B', 'Newyork','18.11.2015');

SELECT p.*, p2.*
FROM #Persons p
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT p1.Person) as countdistinctpersonincity
        FROM
            #Persons p1 
        WHERE
            p1.Person <> p.Person
            AND p1.City = p.City
            AND p1.workingdate = p.workingdate) p2;

DROP TABLE #Persons;
```

The result is this :

```
Person  City      workingdate   countdistinctpersonincity   
A       Newyork   10.11.2015    1   
A       Newyork   11.11.2015    0   
A       Newyork   12.11.2015    0   
B       Newyork   10.11.2015    1   
B       Newyork   15.11.2015    0   
B       Newyork   16.11.2015    0   
B       Newyork   18.11.2015    0
```

Answer (score 4):

One variant:

```
SELECT *
      ,IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY City, Person ORDER BY workingdate) = 1, 1, 0)
FROM Persons
```

[image]

---

For SQL Server before 2012, you can use:

```
SELECT P.*
      ,CASE WHEN DS.[City] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM Persons P
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT City
          ,Person
          ,MIN(workingdate) AS workingdate
    FROM Persons
    GROUP BY City
            ,Person
) DS
    ON P.City = DS.[City]
    AND P.[Person] = DS.[Person]
    AND P.[workingdate] = DS.[workingdate]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this query will give your result. Idea is to check if previous entry sorted by person and date is different so it means we reached new person:

```
select case 
         when Person != lag(Person, 1, 'XXXXXX') over (order by Person, workingdate) then 1 
         else 0 
       end 
  from table;
```

To see how this works here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Persons (
  Person varchar(25),
  City varchar(255),
  workingdate varchar(10)
)

insert into #Persons
values ('A', 'Newyork','10.11.2015'),
       ('A', 'Newyork','11.11.2015'),
       ('A', 'Newyork','12.11.2015'),
       ('B', 'Newyork','10.11.2015'),
       ('B', 'Newyork','15.11.2015'),
       ('B', 'Newyork','16.11.2015'),
       ('B', 'Newyork','18.11.2015')

select p.Person, p.City, p.workingdate,
       case 
         when p.Person != lag(p.Person, 1, 'XXXXXX') over (order by    p.Person, p.workingdate) then 1 
         else 0 
       end 
from   #Persons p
```

the result is:

```
Person  City      workingdate   COLUMN1 
A       Newyork   10.11.2015    1   
A       Newyork   11.11.2015    0   
A       Newyork   12.11.2015    0   
B       Newyork   10.11.2015    1   
B       Newyork   15.11.2015    0   
B       Newyork   16.11.2015    0   
B       Newyork   18.11.2015    0
```